# angular ng-attr- expression with scope.variable in the result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am looking for a solution for my problem.
i have a directive with a scope variable "image". i also have a template file for this directive.

In this template i want to add a style attribute (background URL) if the scope variable is set. My tries ended like that 2 hours ago. i could not find a solution on google or maybe i just dont know how to describe my problem better :)

```
<header ng-attr-style="{image != '' || 'background-image: url( {{image}}) );' }" style="" class="fullscreen">
```

the result should be something like that:

`scope.image = "abc.jpg"
<header style="background-image: url(abc.jpg)">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<header ng-attr-style="{{image ? 'background-image: url(' + image + ') );' : '' }}" style="" class="fullscreen">
```

Comment: thank you very much.
is there also a way to replace the ng-attr-style? or i have to do this with the compile function of the direction manually

Comment: What exactly replace means? You want to change value of ng-att-style dynamically? Then you shoud use scope variable ng-attr-style="some_var" and change it in your controller.

Comment: thanks for your reply and sry for my incorrect question. with replace i mean, when i check the DOM element there ist now the new/correct style. but also there is the ng-attr-style still there. ists like this:
`<header style="background-image: url(aaa);" ng-attr-style="{{image ? 'background-image: url(' + image + ');' : '' }}" >` but what i want is that also the ng-attr-style tag is getting replaced `<header style="background-image: url(aaa);" >`

Comment: May be then use regular style tag instead?

`<header style="{{image ? 'background-image:' + 'url(' + image + ');' : ''}}" class="fullscreen">`